# Oracle PL/SQL group by with date field produces confusing results

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In a query, I did a GROUP BY on a date field that produced these summary results. The Query was like this:

```
SELECT  
(CASE 
WHEN std.attribute_1 like '%709%' OR std.attribute_1 like '%999%' THEN 'COMPA' -- COMPA invoices either start with 709 or 999
WHEN h.manual_upload = 'Y' then 'MANUAL_UPLOAD'  
ELSE 'OTHER' END) AS BILLING_SOURCE, std.created_on, COUNT(DISTINCT std.invoice_number) AS COUNT_OF_INVOICES
FROM onebiller.t_std_in_detail_his std
INNER JOIN onebiller.t_std_in_header h
ON h.job_id =  std.job_id
WHERE std.invoice_number IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY (CASE 
WHEN std.attribute_1 like '%709%' OR std.attribute_1 like '%999%' THEN 'COMPA' -- COMPA invoices either start with 709 or 999
WHEN h.manual_upload = 'Y' then 'MANUAL_UPLOAD'  
ELSE 'OTHER' END), std.created_on
ORDER BY std.created_on ASC
```

Note these results for 3 datetimes on 19-Mar-2021 from the created_on field.

[image]

I then used TRUNC(created_on) to try to group all the records from a single day. This was the updated query:

```
SELECT  
(CASE 
WHEN std.attribute_1 like '%709%' OR std.attribute_1 like '%999%' THEN 'COMPA' -- COMPA invoices either start with 709 or 999
WHEN h.manual_upload = 'Y' then 'MANUAL_UPLOAD'  
ELSE 'OTHER' END) AS BILLING_SOURCE, TRUNC(std.created_on), COUNT(DISTINCT std.invoice_number) AS COUNT_OF_INVOICES
FROM onebiller.t_std_in_detail_his std
INNER JOIN onebiller.t_std_in_header h
ON h.job_id =  std.job_id
WHERE std.invoice_number IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY (CASE 
WHEN std.attribute_1 like '%709%' OR std.attribute_1 like '%999%' THEN 'COMPA' -- COMPA invoices either start with 709 or 999
WHEN h.manual_upload = 'Y' then 'MANUAL_UPLOAD'  
ELSE 'OTHER' END), TRUNC(std.created_on)
ORDER BY TRUNC(std.created_on) ASC
```

I was expecting a result that would sum the 3 highlighted rows from the first query (2+165+164) instead I received a count of 166 for 19-Mar-2021. Why didn't I get the sum of (2+165+164)?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Because you have the same invoice number repeated at different times on the same day. As a simpler example, say you have:

| CREATED_ON | INVOICE_NUMBER |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-03-19 09:00:00 | 1 |
| 2021-03-19 09:00:00 | 2 |
| 2021-03-19 12:00:00 | 2 |
| 2021-03-19 15:00:00 | 1 |
| 2021-03-19 15:00:00 | 2 |
| 2021-03-19 15:00:00 | 3 |

That shows 6 rows, but only three distinct invoice numbers - 1, 2 and 3.

A simplified version of your first query gives:

```
SELECT std.created_on,
  COUNT(DISTINCT std.invoice_number) AS COUNT_OF_INVOICES
FROM std
GROUP BY std.created_on
ORDER BY std.created_on ASC
```

| CREATED_ON | COUNT_OF_INVOICES |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-03-19 09:00:00 | 2 |
| 2021-03-19 12:00:00 | 1 |
| 2021-03-19 15:00:00 | 3 |

The sum of those counts currently matches the number of rows in the table, 6. (I haven't included any duplicates at the same time, so the `distinct` isn't doing anything at the moment, again to keep it simple.) The row for 09:00 counts invoice numbers 1 and 2; the row for 12:00 only counts 2; and the row for 15:00 counts 1, 2 and 3. The counts in all three rows include a count for invoice number 2, the first and third include a count for invoice number 1 - so the same invoice numbers are being counted multiple times.

```
SELECT TRUNC(std.created_on) as created_on,
  COUNT(DISTINCT std.invoice_number) AS COUNT_OF_INVOICES
FROM std
GROUP BY TRUNC(std.created_on)
ORDER BY TRUNC(std.created_on) ASC
```

| CREATED_ON | COUNT_OF_INVOICES |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-03-19 00:00:00 | 3 |

Now the single result is three, because that's how many distinct invoice numbers there are that day - it's now counting 1, 2 and 3 once each, not 2x2, 3x2 and 1x3.

If you didn't have the `distinct` then the second query would also get 6, because it wouldn't be eliminating the duplicates seen in the first query.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OEPwFKDa)

Comment: Thank you Alex for the detailed and thoughtful answer.